# Remove elements from List(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, list

I use the removeRange function to remove a couple elements from a list, but the Count of the list seems to be intact, so I assume it didn't work the way I expected it too.... so, how do you remove elements? I mean, reduce the list's Count value ultimately.

Comment: maybe we could see a short example of how you're removing the elements and then checking the count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RemoveRange` does indeed work. The first argument is the index at which you want to start removing, and the second is the number of elements to remove.

So:

```
Dim list = New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3}
list.RemoveRange(0, 2)
Console.WriteLine(list.Count)
```

The above code will remove the elements `1` and `2` from the list and output "1" (the number of elements in the list after removal).

Answer (score 0):

The `List(Of T).RemoveRange` function does an in place removal so you should be seeing a modification to the `Count` property.  The only way you will not see a modification to the `Count` entry or a thrown exception is if you pass 0 for the count parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I think you what you are doing is
Suppose we have `List` of `Persons` class named as `lstPersons`
then
`lstPersons.RemoveRange(..)`

But it should be like

`lstPersons = lstPersons.RemoveRange(..)`

Comment: This is completely wrong.  `RemoveRange` is defined as `Public Sub RemoveRange (index As Integer, count As Integer)`.  It doesn't return a value.